# Куда они направились?

Tags: стилистика

"И они не торопясь направились из гостиной пить чай".
Возможно ли в данном случае не говорить "куда" направились, а только "что делать"? Всегда ли направляются "из", а потом "в"?

Comment: "Из" названной точки зачем-либо всегда _**от**правляются_, "направляются" же в явно обозначенном направлении на другое место (_куда_ именно, а не "зачем").

Answer (score 1):

Направиться можно либо куда-то (предлоги в/на), либо с целью что-то сделать (без предлогов, просто глагол), или и то и другое. "Из" можно добавлять, а можно и не добавлять — по желанию.

Некорректные предложения:

> Они направились из гостиной. Они направились.

Корректные предложения:

> Они направились в дом пить чай. Они направились в дом. Они направились пить чай. Они направились за чаем.

Добавление:

> Можно ли тогда написать таким образом: "И они, не торопясь, вышли из гостиной и отправились пить чай"?

Это, конечно, корректно. Но зачем загромождать предложение на ровном месте? Мне нравится первоначальный вариант больше чем варианты с "отправились". Он более четкий, простой и выражает больше смысла на единицу слов.

А вот доказательство что можно писать "направиться + инфинитив":

[Ссылка](https://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&api=1.0&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&mydocsize=&mode=main&lang=ru&sort=i_grtagging&nodia=1&text=lexgramm&parent1=0&level1=0&lex1=%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F&gramm1=&sem1=&flags1=&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&parent2=0&level2=0&min2=1&max2=1&lex2=&gramm2=V%2Cinf&sem2=&flags2=&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2)

Comment: А со словом "отправиться" будет тот же смысл?

Comment: Да, смысл почти тот же. Отправиться имеет более широкое обстоятельство места, а направиться более конкретное.

Comment: Отправляются тоже только куда-то или с целью что-либо сделать?

Comment: Да, можно и так сказать. В предложении эта цель уже не обязана быть выражена, но в контексте она все равно обязана быть: Им предстоял долгий путь. Они отправились на рассвете. (отправились в путь). Поэтому всегда лучше явно указывать то куда или зачем отправились.

Comment: Можно ли тогда написать таким образом: "И они, не торопясь, вышли из гостиной и отправились пить чай"?

Comment: "Это, конечно, корректно. Но зачем загромождать предложение на ровном месте?" Потому что указание места в истории является важным:) Есть определенный замысел.

Comment: Так место никуда не потерялось. Вы указали его и в первоначальном предложении и в новом. Оба предложения корректны, оба содержат место, но одно проще другого.

Comment: Мне показалось, что первоначальное предложение вы предложили перестроить.

Answer (score 1):

> Возможно ли в данном случае не говорить "куда" направились, а только
> "что делать"?

Вы имеете в виду, допустимо ли такое построение фразы, без указания физической точки назначения?
**Да, допустимо.**
Направиться (куда?) не обязательно требует указания физической или геометрической локации. Можно  использовать и смысловую цель: "С какой целью направляетесь?"

> Озадаченный происходящим, Вячик направился за веником и ведром.
> [Федор Чернин. Вячик Слонимиров и его путешествие в непонятное //
> «Звезда», 2002]
>
> Выйдя из подвала, Руслан отчистил себя от сажи и копоти тем же
> раствором, оделся и направился легализовывать свое существование. [А.
> С. Лукьянов. Зубы // «Уральская новь», 2001]

Примеры - из Нацкорпуса, не авторитетные, конечно, но уж какие нашел.

(+) ===
Сколь либо существенной разницы в правилах употребления "отправиться" и "направиться" в подобном контексте не вижу.

(++) ===

А вот и пример абсолютно авторитетный.

> Я взял свой портфель и направился искать пристанища. [Д. С. Лихачев.
> Воспоминания (1995)]

Comment: Спасибо. Тогда здесь просто встает вопрос о благозвучности? "Направиться из гостиной пить чай" не совсем звучит?..

Comment: *Тогда здесь просто встает вопрос о благозвучности?* - о стилистической приемлемости. я бы так сказал. Благозвучие - всё-таки нечто другое.

Comment: *"Направиться из гостиной пить чай" не совсем звучит?* - Это субъективно. По мне так если не задаваться совсем уж строгими нормами изящной словесности, то вполне допустимо в разговоре.